# Android write json file from url

Tags: java, android, json

I'm working on JSON. I wrote code which can to parse JSON and show listview(images and text).
Now I want to save my JSON in file (json.txt). 
This is a my code. I try to save JSON but when I debug it on my json.txt file saved only first data, but I have 20 data in JSON
if anyone know solution please help .......

```
    jsonparser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonparser.getJSONfromURL(URL);
        try {

            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("journal", jsonobject.getString(KEY_journal));
                map.put("image", jsonobject.getString(KEY_image));
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString(KEY_title));
                map.put("description",
                        jsonobject.getString(KEY_description));
                map.put("JournalID", jsonobject.getString(KEY_JournalID));
                map.put("pubDate", jsonobject.getString(KEY_pubDate));
                map.put("statID", jsonobject.getString(KEY_statID));

                Content cont = new Content(jsonobject.getString("journal"),
                        jsonobject.getString("image"),
                        jsonobject.getString("title"),
                        jsonobject.getString("pubDate"),
                        jsonobject.getString("description"),
                        jsonobject.getString("JournalID"),
                        jsonobject.getString("statID"));
                contents.add(cont);




                    yourFile = new File("/sdcard/json.txt");

                    try {
                        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                new FileOutputStream(yourFile), "UTF-8");
                        writer.write(jsonobject.toString());
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (writer != null) {
                            try {
                                writer.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

open your file in append  mode.

```
new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(yourFile,true), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: i did not understand you .. i changed but it but i have  syntacs error

Comment: see my updated answer.if it solve your problem then mark it as solve.

Comment: can you post method = JSONObject jsonfromurl = jsonparser.getJSONfromURL(URL);

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate variable for the JSONObject retrieved from the URL, and the one used to loop the data array:

```
    jsonparser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject jsonfromurl = jsonparser.getJSONfromURL(URL);
        try {

            jsonarray = jsonfromurl.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("journal", jsonobject.getString(KEY_journal));
                map.put("image", jsonobject.getString(KEY_image));
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString(KEY_title));
                map.put("description",
                        jsonobject.getString(KEY_description));
                map.put("JournalID", jsonobject.getString(KEY_JournalID));
                map.put("pubDate", jsonobject.getString(KEY_pubDate));
                map.put("statID", jsonobject.getString(KEY_statID));

                Content cont = new Content(jsonobject.getString("journal"),
                        jsonobject.getString("image"),
                        jsonobject.getString("title"),
                        jsonobject.getString("pubDate"),
                        jsonobject.getString("description"),
                        jsonobject.getString("JournalID"),
                        jsonobject.getString("statID"));
                contents.add(cont);




                    yourFile = new File("/sdcard/json.txt");

                    try {
                        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                new FileOutputStream(yourFile), "UTF-8");
                        writer.write(jsonfromurl.toString());
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (writer != null) {
                            try {
                                writer.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the same style as [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html). From what I can see, they actually write bytes to the FileOutputStream, whereas you try to write a string. FileOutputStream only accepts bytes, as per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28int%29).

Try `writer.write(jsonobject.toString().getBytes());` instead.

Comment: thank you i changed but when i put your code i have syntacs error